# Плавная анимация передвижения одной окружности внутри другой

Tags: javascript, canvas

Даны 2 окружности, вложенные одна в другую:
необходимо реализовать отталкивание внутренней от курсора при этом она не должна выходить за границы внешней.

```js
class Circle {
    constructor(node) {
        this.DOMElement = node;
        this.ctx = this.DOMElement.getContext('2d');
        this.dx = 0;
        this.dy = 0;
        this.x = this.DOMElement.width / 2,
        this.y = this.DOMElement.height / 2,
        this.ballRadius = 39;
        this.cirleRadius = this.DOMElement.width / 2 - 50
    }
    drawCircle(x, y, radius, fill) {
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx[`${fill.fill}Style`] = fill.color;
        this.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        this.ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        this.ctx[fill.fill]();
        this.ctx.closePath();
    }
    render() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.DOMElement.width, this.DOMElement.height);
        this.drawCircle(
            this.DOMElement.width / 2, 
            this.DOMElement.height / 2, 
            this.cirleRadius,
            {fill: 'stroke', color: '#34648e'}
        );
        this.drawCircle(
            this.x, 
            this.y, 
            this.ballRadius,
            {fill: 'fill', color: '#0294bf'}
        );
        if(Math.pow(this.x - this.DOMElement.width / 2, 2) + Math.pow(this.y - this.DOMElement.height / 2, 2) >= Math.pow(this.cirleRadius - this.ballRadius, 2) ) {
          // ????
        }
        const frame = requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this))
    }
    
    init() {
        let currentX = 0;
        let currentY = 0;
        let distance = 0;
        let speed = 10;

        this.DOMElement.onmousemove = (event) => {
            let mouseX = event.clientX - this.DOMElement.offsetLeft - 10;
            let mouseY = event.clientY - this.DOMElement.offsetTop - this.DOMElement.scrollTop + window.pageYOffset - 14;
            
            let xResult = mouseX - currentX;
            let yResult = mouseY - currentY;
            distance = Math.sqrt(xResult * xResult + yResult * yResult);
            if(Math.pow(mouseX - this.x, 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - this.y, 2) <= Math.pow(this.ballRadius + 5, 2) ) {
                this.x += xResult / distance * speed;
                this.y += yResult / distance * speed;
            }
            currentX = mouseX;
            currentY = mouseY;
            
        }
        this.render();
        
    }
    
    
}
const circle = new Circle(document.querySelector('#canvas'));
    circle.init();
```

```css
.canvas {
    border: 15px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="590" height="600">
```

Подскажите как реализовать планый "отскок" шара от прикосновения к нему курсором на некую дистанцию и при этом такой же плавный "отскок" от границы внешней окружности при столкновении.

Comment: это, батюшка, вам физику нужно реализовывать)

Comment: @ThisMan так это я и справшиваю, может кто подскажет как реализуются такие вещи, или скинет полезную ссылочку где можно почитать.

Comment: при этом всем есть гравитация или нет?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  нет, просто "отскок" на определенное растояние в зависимости от направления толчка мыши

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы движения были без рывков, необходимо положения считать исходя из скоростей и времени между кадрами.

Т.е. зная положение объекта в прошлом кадре, его направление,  скорость движения и сколько прошло с прошлого кадра секунд - вычисляем новое положение.

Собрал маленький пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Я завел объект, описывающий состояние шарика.
2. Повесил слушатель, который обновляет глобальное положение мыши по `mousemove`
3. Написал цикл отрисовки (рекурсивный вызов через `requestAnimationFrame`), который берет значение положения шарика из объекта-состояния и рисует его + рисует внешний круг.
4. Запустил независимый от отрисовки цикл(`setInterval`), который меняет состояние шарика. Он делает 3 вещи:

   - Обрабатывает положение мыши относительно шарика, и когда произошло столкновение устанавливает шарику скорость и вектор движения.
   - Считает новое положения шарика исходя из его текущего положения, вектора его движения и скорости. Постепенно уменьшает скорость движения.
   - Обрабатывает столкновения с внешним кругом, подсчитывая новый отраженный вектор движения

Отраженный вектор равен исходному вектору минус вектор нормали умноженный на двойное [скалярное произведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) вектора нормали в точке соударения и исходного вектора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`r = i−2(i⋅n)n`

Вот рабочий пример:

```js
// координаты мыши относительно центра канвы.
let x = 0, y = 0; 

// глобальный слушатель мышки
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let z = window.getComputedStyle(canvas).zoom || 1;     
  x = e.pageX/z - e.target.offsetLeft - canvas.width/2,
  y = e.pageY/z - e.target.offsetTop - canvas.height/2;
});

let ball = {
  
  r: 50,    // радиус шарика
  x: 0,     // координата по х центра шарика
  y: 0,     // координата по y центра шарика
  speed: 0, // скорость движения
  dirx: 0,  // компонент x вектора движения шарика
  diry: 0,  // компонент y вектора движения шарика
  damp: 10, // скорость уменьшения скорости движения (сопротивление)
  collision: false, // признак коллизии с внешним кругом
  
  // функция, которая проверяет наличие коллизии шарика с внешним кругом
  hitOuterCircleCheck: function() {
  
   let dr = 195-this.r; //разница радиусов
   // по теореме пифагора проверяем выход за пределы круга (коллизию)
   if (this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y > dr*dr) {
   
      // если коллизия уже была обсчитана, но шарик еще не вернулся в круг, 
      // чтобы он не застревал больше не надо обсчитывать коллизии, поэтому выходим
      if (this.collision)
          return;
          
      // устанавливаем для шарика признак коллизии    
      this.collision = true; 

      // далее идет код расчета нового вектора движения

      // найдем вектор нормали. тут он берется приближенно, 
      // в точке центра шарика в момент обсчета коллизии, 
      // при том что шарик уже проскочил границу. по идее тут 
      // необходимо посчитать точку соударения геометрически. 
      let max = Math.max(Math.abs(this.x), Math.abs(this.y)); 
      let nx = -this.x/max;
      let ny = -this.y/max;

      // найдем новый вектор движения по формуле 
      // r = i−2(i⋅n)n , где
      // i - исходный вектор
      // n - нормаль 
      // ⋅ знак скалярного произведения

      let dot2 = this.dirx * nx * 2 + this.diry * ny * 2
      this.dirx = this.dirx-dot2*nx;
      this.diry = this.diry-dot2*ny;

      // нормализуем вектор движения
      max = Math.max(Math.abs(this.dirx), Math.abs(this.diry));
      this.dirx /= max;
      this.diry /= max;
    } else {
    
      // сбрасываем признак коллизии когда шарик вернулся в круг.
      this.collision = false;
    }
  },
  
  // функция проверки коллизии шарика и мышки
  hitMouseCheck: function() {
  
    // если есть коллизия с внешним кругом игнорируем мышку
    if (this.collision) 
      return;
  
    // разница координат мышки и шарика
    let dx = this.x - x; 
    let dy = this.y - y;

    // проверяем по теореме Пифагора столкновение с мышкой
    if (dx*dx + dy*dy < ball.r*ball.r) { 
      // задаем вектор движения и нормализуем его
      let max = Math.max(Math.abs(dx), Math.abs(dy));
      if (!max) return;
      this.dirx = dx/max;
      this.diry = dy/max;

      // задаем скорость
      this.speed = 300;
    }
  },
  
  // тут осуществляется передвижение
  // dt - кол-во секунд с прошлого обсчета
  doMove: function(dt) { 
  
    // к текущей координате прибавляем вектор скорости помноженный 
    // на значение скорости помноженные на прошедшее время
    this.x += this.dirx*this.speed*dt; 
    this.y += this.diry*this.speed*dt;
    
    // тормозим объект, так же на значение зависящее от времени
    this.speed = Math.max(0, this.speed - this.damp*dt); 
  }
};

// цикл прверок, не зависит от цикла отрисовки, 
// все проверки запускаются дискретно, через фиксированное время 10 мс
// если считать "физику" в requestAnimationFrame все будет печально.
let t = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  // считаем сколько времени прошло с прошлого обсчета
  let dt = new Date().getTime() - t; 
  ball.hitMouseCheck();
  ball.doMove(dt/1000);
  ball.hitOuterCircleCheck();
  t = new Date().getTime();
}, 5);

// далее нет никаких фокусов

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2)
  circle(0, 0, 195);
  circle(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r);
  ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2)
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function circle(x,y,r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0"><canvas width="400" height="400"/></body>
```

В этом алгоритме есть неточности, точнее недоработки, но в этом примере они несущественны.

1. В момент обсчета столкновения шарика, когда успешно прошла проверка коллизии с внешним кругом, шарик уже находится за пределами окружности, нормаль я определяю именно в точке центра шарика, а не в точке столкновения. точку эту можно и посчитать, но это усложнит пример.
2. Не хватает переноса шарика обратно в область внешнего круга, с учетом изменения вектора движения в точке соударения, когда он находится уже за границей. Это выражается в том что даже иногда визуально видно как шарик слегка выходит за границы.

Comment: Запустил пример и внутренняя окружность не реагирует на мышь (просто мимо проходил, заинтерсовался вопросом :))

Comment: @gil9red починил ff

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и пример кода, нечто подобное я реализовал, правда иногда шарик прилипает к курсору и нужно "стряхнуть" его мышкой.

Comment: Буду потихоньку разбираться в Вашем примере, хотя при наличии комментариев это было бы куда легче.

Comment: @pepel_xD я старался чтобы было не запутано, попозже напишу комментарии, вы скажите если что то не понятно

Comment: У меня легко получается протолкнуть маленькую окружность сквозь большую.

Comment: @Igor я там писал какая тому причина, надо это обходить :) но тогда пример будет много сложнее

Comment: @Igor на самом деле оказалось что достаточно добавить одно условие, которое даже уже посчитано..

Comment: @pepel_xD ключевой момент в разделении состояния, логики и рендера плюс учет времени